# Firefox wont put my divs side by side

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm having problems making my site look good in Firefox. I have a div and then two divs inside the first one and I want the two that are inside two be side by side. This is the HTML:

```
<div class="gluggi3">
    <h2 class="aust">Veðurspá</h2>
    <div class="vedurspa">Some content</div>
    <div id="map-canvas">More content</div>
</div>
```

and then the CSS:

```
.gluggi3{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: solid;
    border-color: magenta;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.vedurspa {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

#map-canvas {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
}
```

This code works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox, in Firefox the div with the class 'vedurspa' dissappears. I tried using inline, inline-block and initialising left like suggested in other questions, but still no luck. Can anyone tell me how I can make them stay side by side in Firefox? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you have a `padding-right: 50px;` on `.vedurspa`, therefor they are not side by side, removing that would solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

It's not a FireFox issue.  When the viewport is to narrow, #map-canvas will start wrapping.

Consider this:

```
.gluggi3{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-color: magenta;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.vedurspa {   
    width: 50%;
    padding-right: 50px;
        float: left;
}

#map-canvas {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
      float: left;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vUvhq/

Also, remove your comma in the first .gluggi3 class

```
.gluggi3,{}
```

to

```
.gluggi3{}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you added the padding-right to .verdurspa so there would be space between the blocks.

Try adding `float: right;` to #map-canvas